# Continuous extension simple question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,3)\rightarrow(1,2)$ be a decreasing continuous function.

**Prove that $f$ is continuously extendable to a continuous function $g:[0,3]\rightarrow[1,2]$.**

My try: I feel this is super easy, but I don't seem to get it.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=3$ and $x_n<3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $(f(x_n))$ is bounded and decreasing, therefore convergent. Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ exists, and we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{x\to 3^-} f(x)$.

I don't know how to proceed.. $f$ need not be surjective, therefore I don't know what to do.

Comment: Take $g(3)=\lim f(x_n)$, $g(3)$ is well defined as $f$ is continuous on $(3-\epsilon,3)$, then show $g$ is continuous at $3$

Comment: $(x_n)$ should be also given by positive numbers and be increasing, otherwise $f(x_n)$ is not necessarily decreasing. Define then $g(3) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)$. Repeat a similar argument at $0$.

Comment: @Gibbs yes, but how do I know that $g(3)$ and $f$ is continuous at $3$? And also, where does the argument with the sequence go wrong if $f$ is not continuous? Since I don't use the continuity of $f$ anywhere..

Comment: You know that $f$ is continuous, but $g$ coincides with $f$ in the interior of $[0,3]$, so $g$ is continuous on $(0,3)$. Now $g$ is continuous at $3$ if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3^-} g(x) = g(3)$. When $x$ goes towards $3$ from the left, $g(x)$ is equal to $f(x)$. You set $g(3) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 3^-} f(x)$, which then means $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3^-} g(x) = g(3)$. Therefore $g$ is continuous at $3$. So you are done. Similar argument at $0$.

Comment: This does not help at all